# How to modify attribute of an object stored in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to modify the attributes of an object stored in an array.

Specifically, I have an array of `qb` "tuples" that store name, touchdowns, etc. (and the array definitely holds the values correctly and I normally refer to them as `pp.passing_yds`) and I want to for example multiply the amount of touchdowns this `qb` has by 10

Here is my attempt:

```
for pp in qb:
    qb[pp.passing_tds] *= 10
```

However, I get an index out of bounds error here which makes it seem like I'm multiplying the index when I'm actually trying to multiply the attribute.

Comment: ok so i tried another way `for pp in qbPastFive:
                qbPastFive[pp].passing_yds *= 10` and that says list indicies must be integers and not my data type

Comment: What happens when you just use "pp.passing_tds *= 10" in your for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments: I think all you have to do is to modify your `for-loop` to:

```
for pp in qb:
    pp.passing_tds *= 10
```

assuming that `qp` is your list of objects. Then `pp` is an object and you directly change its attribute.

Comment: great ill try that out, I accidently delete my python file from my server with no back up so hopefulyy i can find a way to get it back

Comment: Good luck! I highly recommend using github, gitlab or something comparable to avoid such troubles. And let me know if it then works for you and whether you need any further explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for pp in qb:
    pp.passing_tds *= 10
```

What you tried to do was (assuming `pp.passing_tds = 45`)

```
qb[45] # <- the 45th item in the qb list, which may not exist, if qb is a small list
```